# memory error trying to make a wordcloud

Tags: r

first i run this line executed successfully   corpus table size is 2.39.4 MB

```
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
```

but facing error when run the following line

```
m <- as.matrix(tdm)

error is showing as follows
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 15.9 Gb
```

image is attached

Comment: Your `TermDocumentMatrix` is probably a sparse matrix. Doing `as.matrix()` forces it to expand to full size. Sounds like you just don't have enough RAM to hold the full size matrix. Why are you trying to do `as.matrix`?

Comment: FYI, I [edited your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (to `code`-ify your code/error) and removed the `rstudio*` tags, as this is about neither the desktop IDE (`[rstudio]`) nor the web-based IDE (`[rstudio-server]`).

Comment: maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890935/why-does-as-matrix-result-in-memory-overload-while-running-text-mining-in-r re comments using the `slam` library

Comment: @MrFlick  SIR i am trying this code to draw wordcloud
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(tweetshash)
m <- as.matrix(tdm1)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
pal <- brewer.pal(9, "BuGn")
pal <- pal[-(1:2)]
png("wordcloud.png", width=1280,height=800)
wordcloud(d$word,d$freq, scale=c(8,.3),min.freq=2,max.words=100, random.order=T, rot.per=.15, colors=pal, vfont=c("sans serif","plain"))

Comment: @MrFlick sir i have a csv file contain more than 58900 tweets i want to draw word clod  and Word Association Graph
This cluster graph is useful for visualizing associations among the most frequent terms in a corpus of Tweets, and if # and @ symbols are retained after cleaning a corpus, then it provides a visual for how the top terms in a corpus are associated with the top hashtags and username mentions.      

 sir actually abouve graph i want to draw please please help me